# How can I add a period after the first three characters and then a ' every 3 characters after?

Tags: php

How can I add a period after the first three characters and then a ' every 3 characters after?

```
Example
$number = 1100000
Output = 1'100.000

Example2
$number = 560000
Output = 560.000

Example3
$number = 1000256000
Output = 1'000'256.000
```

**I tried number_format but it will add the same symbol (. , ')...thanks!!**

```
$number = 1100000;
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 0, '.', "'");
Output: 1'100'000

$number = 1100000;
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 3, '.', "'");
Output: 1'100'000.000

$number = 1100000;
echo chunk_split($number,1,".");
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you first try something(write a code) on your own before asking for solution?

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: Try dividing by 1000 before formatting

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track with `number_format` but you have to specify all 4 parameters to achieve the result you are looking for. You also need to divide the number by 1000 to avoid the extra decimal places.

```
echo number_format($number / 1000, 3, "." , "'");
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e2c-a6q

Comment: I tried this but it adds '.000' at the end of the number making it of "longer" value

Comment: @antonioj1015 Edited, you also have to divide the number by 1000 first.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently, try this function:

```
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) { 
    if ($fractional) { 
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number); 
    } 
    while (true) { 
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number); 
        if ($replaced != $number) { 
            $number = $replaced; 
        } else { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return $number; 
}
```

edit for your use